# the folder name and the Joomla component link after installation

Tags: php, joomla

I wrote a component for Joomla. Everything works but after the installation the folder name is as follows: com_.

And the component cannot be accessed at the backend. Please help me.

yoodabir.php

```
    if( ! JFactory::getUser()->authorise('core.manage', 'com_yoodabir'))
 {
throw new Exception(JText::_('JERROR_ALERTNOAUTHOR'), 403);
 }

$controller = JControllerLegacy::getInstance('yoodabir');

   JLoader::register('yoodabirHelper', JPATH_COMPONENT.'/helpers yoodabir.php');

   $controller->execute(JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('task'));

  $controller->redirect();
```

yoodabir.xml:

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <extension type="component" version="3.0" method="upgrade">
      <name>دبیرخانه</name>
      <creationDate>2018</creationDate>
      <author>hh</author>
     <authorEmail>hhh</authorEmail>
     <authorUrl>hhh</authorUrl>
     <copyright>hh</copyright>
    <license>hhh</license>
   <version>0.0.2</version>
   <description></description>

    <install>
    <sql>
          <file driver="mysql"    charset="utf8">sql/install.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
        </sql>
     </install>

       <uninstall>
    <sql>
          <file driver="mysql"     harset="utf8">sql/uninstall.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
    </sql>
     </uninstall>

     <files folder="site">
        <filename>yoodabir.php</filename>
        <filename>controller.php</filename>
       <filename>index.html</filename>
      <folder>views</folder>
       <folder>models</folder>
         <folder>assets</folder>
         <folder>uploadfile</folder>
         <folder>helpers</folder>
       <folder>controller</folder>

        </files>

        <administration>
       <menu>دبیرخانه</menu>
       <files folder="admin">
        <filename>yoodabir.php</filename>
        <filename>access.xml</filename>
        <filename>config.xml</filename>
        <filename>controller.php</filename>
        <folder>controllers</folder>
        <folder>models</folder>
        <folder>views</folder>
        <folder>helpers</folder>
        <folder>tables</folder>
        <folder>sql</folder>
        <folder>assets</folder>
         </files>
        </administration>
       </extension>
```

Comment: What error you are getting when you are opening your component in the backend or administrator side.

Answer (score 1):

Joomla installer uses the `<name>` tag to determine the folder name for the extension, but it probably doesn't work well with non-latin alphabets, so try changing to `<name>yoodabir</name>`

also, there is a space in the path of your helper.